Unitary transformations in quantum mechanics
I have a question regarding the unitary transformation in quantum mechanics. Suppose the original Hamiltonian $H_1(t)$ satisfies the Schrodinger equation
\begin{equation}
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\Psi_1(t)\rangle = H_1(t) | \Psi_1(t) \rangle
\end{equation}
The unitary transformation says that if I introduce a unitary operator $U(t)$ and transform the Hamiltonian and wave function as follows:
\begin{equation}
H_2(t) = U(t) \left[ H_1(t) - i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right] U^\dagger(t)
\end{equation}
and $|\Psi_2(t)\rangle = U(t) |\Psi_1(t)\rangle$.
The transformed quantities satisfy:
\begin{equation}
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\Psi_2(t)\rangle = H_2(t) | \Psi_2(t) \rangle
\end{equation}
My question is: How does the Green's function $$G_{ij}(t,t') = -i\langle c_i(t) c_j^\dagger(t')\rangle$$ in the original system transform after the unitary transformation?
*** A simple example ***
Consider a dimer $$H(t) = v(a^\dagger b + b^\dagger a) + \epsilon_a(t) a^\dagger a.$$ By introducing a unitary operator $$U(t) = \exp\{i\int_{t_0}^t d\bar{t} \epsilon_a(\bar{t})(a^\dagger a + b^\dagger b)\}, $$ the transformed Hamiltonian becomes $$H'(t) = v(a^\dagger b + b^\dagger a) - \epsilon_a(t) b^\dagger b.$$
In this example, the transformation merely redefines the energy reference. Since my original question is much complex than this, i'd like to understand the general relationship between the GFs before and after the transformation.

You have used the interaction representation of quantum mechanics in your example above. The Green's function for a many-body system is defined in the Interaction representation, where the time-evolution is governed by the non-interacting term of the total Hamiltonian. So, applying a unitary transformation will shift the time coordinates. In essence, the Green's function is invariant to unitary time-evolution operators. What actually changes is the basis of the system. So, it defines the same physics in different basis states.

None of this is true. The bits that the OP had written had not yet implemented interaction picture. The usual interaction picture unitary transform of Green's functions will also incur a phase shifting of the S matrix elements, which, luckily, we do not care due to immeasureability of overall phase shifts. It does matter when we want to superpose stuff together, though.

Correct! You've re-stated my response. Since both the eigenket and the operator are time-dependent, this must be in the interaction picture. OP did not explicitly state which representation they wrote down, but it's clear from the notation. I've attached a link to the wikipedia page describing the interaction picture in detail. There is a table that will clarify this issue, or you could reference Marder's textbook for many-body physics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture#:~:text=The%20interaction%20picture%20is%20a,the%20Hamiltonian%20and%20state%20vectors.

thanks for the reply. To clarify my question, let me provide a simple example. Consider a dimer $H(t) = v(a^\dagger b + b^\dagger a) + \epsilon_a(t) a^\dagger a$. By introducing a unitary operator $U(t) = e^{i\int_{t_0}^t d\bar{t} \epsilon_a(\bar{t})(a^\dagger a + b^\dagger b)} $, the transformed Hamiltonian becomes $H'(t) = v(a^\dagger b + b^\dagger a) - \epsilon_a(t) b^\dagger b$.

In this simple case, the unitary transformation essentially redefines the energy reference. However, my actual question is more complex, and I'd like to understand the general relationship between the GFs before and after such a transformation.
